# Convert requests object to pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a request object to a pandas dataframe and then save it as a csv. I'm having a bunch of issues. My code has some commented out attempts at what I've tried. If I target [query] I just get the headers.

When I print the j_data variable I get the whole data returned, when I add `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j_data)` I get this error: `ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.` The for statement was an attempt to save the headers on the first row and then the data afterwards. I get errors about `row.keys()`.

Here is my code:

```
import requests

import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
import io

url = 'https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/trades.v1/exchanges/cbse/spot/btc-usd/aggregations/count_ohlcv_vwap?interval=1h'

KEY = 'xxx'

headers = {
   "X-Api-Key": KEY,
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
j_data = r.json()
moredata = j_data['query']

#print(j_data)
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w')
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(j_data)
#df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j_data)
print(df)

csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file) 
# Counter variable used for writing  
# headers to the CSV file 
count = 0

for row in j_data: 
    if count == 0: 
  
        # Writing headers of CSV file 
        header = row.keys() 
        csv_writer.writerow(header) 
        count += 1
  
    # Writing data of CSV file 
    csv_writer.writerow(row.values()) 
  
data_file.close()
```

Here is what the data looks like:

```
{'query': {'page_size': 100, 'exchange': 'cbse', 'instrument_class':
'spot', 'instrument': 'btc-usd', 'interval': '1h', 'sort': 'desc',
'ch': True, 'aggregation': 'count_ohlcv_vwap', 'data_version': 'v1',
'commodity': 'trades', 'request_time': '2021-01-19T19:45:06.716Z'},
'time': '2021-01-19T19:45:06.833Z', 'timestamp': 1611085506833,
'data': [{'timestamp': 1611082800000, 'open': '36473.48', 'high':
'36767.14', 'low': '36100', 'close': '36165.7', 'volume':
'1055.9205645800007', 'price': '36471.81712877342', 'count': 9753},
{'timestamp': 1611079200000, 'open': '37181', 'high': '37187.69',
'low': '36453.02', 'close': '36472.2', 'volume':
'1018.0314456899991', 'price': '36872.594925453566', 'count':
12488}, {'timestamp': 1611075600000, 'open': '37383.33', 'high':
'37534.34', 'low': '37042.05', 'close': '37181', 'volume':
'754.3446774100009', 'price': '37246.07621642544', 'count': 10416},
{'timestamp': 1611072000000, 'open': '37349', 'high': '37857',
'low': '37243.96', 'close': '37384.94', 'volume':
'1572.9171879399996', 'price': '37599.8706254367', 'count': 13859},
{'timestamp': 1611068400000, 'open': '37028.03', 'high': '37350',
'low': '36839.23', 'close': '37349', 'volume': '656.1489244499998',
'price': '37118.16456359029', 'count': 8003}, {'timestamp':
1611064800000, 'open': '37129.21', 'high': '37299.99', 'low':
'36950', 'close': '37035.35', 'volume': '824.4022543699986',
'price': '37148.65385601146', 'count': 7835}, {'timestamp':
1611061200000, 'open': '36803.57', 'high': '37250', 'low':
'36803.57', 'close': '37128.46', 'volume': '397.2708292600003',
'price': '37022.32965612193', 'count': 6552}, {'timestamp':
1611057600000, 'open': '37320.27', 'high': '37495.71', 'low':
'36651.25', 'close': '36799.51', 'volume': '684.9236807199975',
'price': '37102.9639283467', 'count': 7128}, {'timestamp':
1611054000000, 'open': '37113.74', 'high': '37328.42', 'low':
'36860.94', 'close': '37316.23', 'volume': '398.46682668000017',
'price': '37075.5347782764', 'count': 4834}, {'timestamp':
1611050400000, 'open': '37103.86', 'high': '37344.2', 'low':
'36790.66', 'close': '37116.06', 'volume': '380.0430927600001',
'price': '37053.491453328854', 'count': 4291}, {'timestamp':
1611046800000, 'open': '37227.39', 'high': '37496.85', 'low':
'37047.96', 'close': '37087.24', 'volume': '340.69701863000074',
'price': '37292.374528954', 'count': 3932}, {'timestamp':
1611043200000, 'open': '37223.61', 'high': '37550', 'low':
'36960.99', 'close': '37218.43', 'volume': '806.0997657399972',
'price': '37311.93823155893', 'count': 7248}, {'timestamp':
1611039600000, 'open': '36671.13', 'high': '37292', 'low':
'36540.97', 'close': '37223.61', 'volume': '686.07088116', 'price':
'36891.216445559054', 'count': 6211}, {'timestamp': 1611036000000,
'open': '36296.98', 'high': '36805.36', 'low': '36235.19', 'close':
'36671.13', 'volume': '579.5915981899989', 'price':
'36583.625675999065', 'count': 6661}, {'timestamp': 1611032400000,
'open': '36338.96', 'high': '36594.76', 'low': '36200', 'close':
'36297.36', 'volume': '603.2984911200011', 'price':
'36414.16925381375', 'count': 6710}}
```

I've also tried adding:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(j_data), orient='columns') and I get this error:
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Answer (score 2):

Your json object is a dict with four keys: 'query', 'time', 'timestamp' and 'data'. I assume you want to load 'data' into a dataframe so you will have to use that key. It is also possible to save a dataframe to csv directly from pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(j_data['data'])
df.to_csv('data_file.csv')
```